# Why Micronaut @EachProperty does not work with value composed by an env var?

Tags: java, micronaut

Suppose I have the following conf class:

```
@EachProperty(value = "some.other.config")
@Data
public class SomeConfiguration {

    private final String name;

    @MapFormat
    private Map<String, String> somMapConf;

    private List<String> someListConf;

    public SomeConfiguration(@Parameter String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

All the properties are loaded when I use hard coded conf: `@EachProperty(value = "some.other.config")`, but whenever I use an environment variable: `@EachProperty(value = "some.{env.var}.config")` only the name is loaded, the other configuration properties (`somMapConf and someListConf`) are being set to `null`.

Here is my config:

```
some:
  other:
    config:
      name1:
        somMapConf:
          key1: value1
          key2: value2
        someListConf:
          - element1
          - element2
          - element2
      name2:
        somMapConf:
          key1: value1
          key2: value2
        someListConf:
          - element1
          - element2
          - element2
```

Comment: Are you trying to load a single set of configurations based on an environment variable or load all configurations and only use one based on an environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to inject envVar with Environment. I am not sure if micronaut is able to see the value in `"some.{env.var}.config"`

```
   public class SomeClass {
        
   private final String envVar;
    
   public SomeConfiguration(Environment environment) { 
        this.envVar = environment.getProperty("env.var"); 
   }
        
            @EachProperty(value = "some." + envVar + ".config")
            @Data
            public class SomeConfig {
                ...
            }
        }
```

Comment: It complains with: "Attribute value must be constant". It can see the value in "some.{env.var}.config", it is loading the name property.

Comment: Can you try to add constructor instead @Value annotation
public SomeConfiguration(Environment environment) {
        this.envVar = environment.getProperty("env.var");
    }